# EF6 One to One or Zero Relationship (Fluent API)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have such classes (simplicified):

```
public class Transaction
{
    public int LocalId { get; set; }
    public int MachineId { get; set; }
    public virtual Machine Machine { get; set; }       
    public int? MoneyId { get; set; }
    public virtual TransactionMoney Money { get; set; }
}

public class Machine
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TransactionMoney
{
    public int LocalId { get; set; }
    public int MachineId { get; set; }
    public virtual Machine Machine { get; set; }
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Transaction Transaction { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to have relationship Transaction 1 <-> 0...1 TransactionMoney where foreign key in Money should be TransactionId and MachineId (connected to transaction's LocalId and MachineId). I need to do this in fluent API.

What I've tried is:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>()
                .HasOptional(t => t.Money)
                .WithRequired(t => t.Transaction)
                .HasForeignKey() <--- there is no such method
```

and in other side

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TransactionMoney>()
    .HasRequired(t => t.Transaction)
    .WithOptional(t => t.Money)
            .HasForeignKey() <--- there is no such method
```

Comment: What is the primary key of the `Transaction`?

Comment: Pair LocalId & MachineId

Comment: Well, then `TransactionMoney` should also have a primary key `LocalId, MachineId` that is also a FK to `Transaction`. That's how 1:1 is implemented in EF.

Comment: Like @GertArnold say, your model is simply incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

<del>You can use something like this</del>

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TransactionMoney>()
    .HasRequired(t => t.Transaction)
    .WithOptional(t => t.Money)
    .Map(a => a.MapKey("TransactionId", "MachineId"));
```

It turns out that the design you are targeting cannot be done in EF. The **closest** I was able to get is as follows. But before I go, there are some things to note. `MoneyId` field is removed from `Transaction`. `LocalId` field is removed from `TransactionMoney`. Foreign key is specified with data annotation. If any of those is unacceptable, just skip the rest.

**Entities:**

```
public class Transaction
{
    public int LocalId { get; set; }
    public int MachineId { get; set; }
    public virtual Machine Machine { get; set; }
    public virtual TransactionMoney Money { get; set; }
}

public class Machine
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TransactionMoney> Money { get; set; }
}

public class TransactionMoney
{
    public int MachineId { get; set; }
    public virtual Machine Machine { get; set; }
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TransactionId,MachineId")]
    public virtual Transaction Transaction { get; set; }
}
```

**Configuration**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>()
    .HasKey(t => new { t.LocalId, t.MachineId })
    .HasRequired(t => t.Machine)
    .WithMany(t => t.Transactions)
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.MachineId);

modelBuilder.Entity<TransactionMoney>()
    .HasRequired(t => t.Machine)
    .WithMany(t => t.Money)
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.MachineId);

modelBuilder.Entity<TransactionMoney>()
    .HasKey(t => new { t.TransactionId, t.MachineId })
    .HasRequired(t => t.Transaction)
    .WithOptional(t => t.Money);
```

Comment: I know but I want to use Foreign Key Association, not Independend Association

Comment: I read that indepdendend association is desired to implementing one-to-one relation in entity framework so I used your way and it works, but in TransactionMoney I have also reference to Machine and it creates another column called Machine_Id. How to make it to use "MachineId" field defined in fluent API?

Comment: @Lukas Sorry mate, looks like it's not possible.